# Sql Server 2005: Today's random records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, random, newid

I can easily get a random record with this:

```
SELECT *    FROM MyTable    ORDER BY NewId()
```

I can easily get a record with "today's date" with this:

```
SELECT *    FROM MyTable    WHERE MyDate = "2010-24-08"  -- db doesn't store times
```

But how would I combind the two?

Get 1 random record... anything with today's date.

If none are found... get 1 random record from yesterday (today-1).

If none are found... get 1 random record from etc, etc, today-2

... until 1 record is found.

Answer (score 6):

Just make the day date the primary order by condition:

```
select top(1) *
from Table
order by Date desc, newid();
```

If you store the dates as full day *and* time, you need to round them out to the day part only: `cast (Date as DATE)` in SQL 2008 or `cast(floor(cast(Date as FLOAT)) as DATETIME)` in pre-2008.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [TOP operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx):

```
  SELECT TOP 1 *    
    FROM MyTable    
   WHERE MyDate = "2010-24-08" 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

...combined with the `ORDER BY NEWID()`.  Without the ORDER BY, you'd get the first inserted row/record of the records returned by the filteration in most cases typically, but the only way to ensure order is with an `ORDER BY` clause.

SQL Server 2005+ supports brackets on the TOP value, so you can use a variable in the brackets without needing to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: a better implementation of what i was going to do.

Comment: What if no record of "2010-24-08" in table as mentioned in question.

Comment: @Muhammad Kashif Nadeem: No rows - `TOP`, like MySQL & PostgreSQL's `LIMIT`, only constrains the number of rows returned from the resulset.

Answer (score 1):

Does this give you what you want?

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY MyDate desc, NewId()
```

This assumes there are no dates later than today.